# Octobercms uploader plugin

Tags: octobercms

I am new to octobercms, I have installed uploader plugin which is working very well in the backend. I want to use the same plugin on front end page. Can anyone give me the proper steps to it?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The Uploader plugin does not work alone, it needs to be used in collaboration with another plugin. Can you give an example of how you would like to use the upload functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You first need a model with a relationship to `System\Models\File` defined like next example:

```
class Project extends Model
{
    public $attachMany = [
        'files' => 'System\Models\File',
    ];
}
```

Take a look at http://octobercms.com/plugin/responsiv-uploader#documentation for next steps to take.

Comment: FYI: As of the current version (432) there are bugs in the base class of `System\Models\File`. If you configured the storage disk for uploaded files to something (like `s3`) other than `local`, some features would not work. To fix it, you can create your own class instead of `System\Models\File` to apply the bug fixes in [this PR](https://github.com/octobercms/library/pull/294) and [this PR](https://github.com/octobercms/october/pull/3347) to override those methods with problem.